# Product integrated with CQ5 to check the content standard?

Tags: adobe, aem, standards-compliance

we currently use Active Standard (a website quality testing service that checks pages for spelling, grammar, broken links, poor HTML code, etc).  I want to understand how they could use this going forward with our new CQ5 site so that content is checked before it goes live.  Since Active Standards is a ‘service’ it currently only checks the live site as that is all it can access.

Do we know if there is a content quality testing tool that could    integrate into the CQ5 authoring environment?

Challenges:

1. How would a service like Active Standards be able to access the
   authoring environment which sits behind a firewall on client's
   network?
2. Is there a product which integrates with CQ5 that can be run at the
   point the author is creating content?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Active Standard but from your description I understand it's a service that accesses a public website via HTTP to check its content.

If that's correct and there's no way to provide it with credentials so that it could access a secured stating version of your website, the only way that I see is exposing the staging content that you want to check on a public URL like staging.mysite.com, maybe adding disclaimers, robots.txt and removing CSS etc. so that people don't mistake it for the actual site. That staging website can then get content from the CQ author in a restricted way, using CQ access control and read-only users for example. But that won't work if you want to keep your staged content secret.

At the CQ level, the observation/notification and workflow mechanisms can be used to process content as soon as it's created, but to use this you need to be able to submit the content to the checking service yourself using HTTP or other clients, instead of having it crawl your staging content by itself.